# A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AuthenticationRequestFilter method public com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, restful-authentication

I am Using RESTful APIs in my application using Jersey 1.6.
Some database is also there.

I have created two .war files in my application. These are deployed on Glassfish server3.0.1 with no issues.(no errors/exceptions).

They make some REST calls to each other for transactions.(It has a proper xml format to send a transaction).

When I try to make a transaction it gives me exceptions like

```
A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AuthenticationRequestFilter method public com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest com.mypack1.mypack2.resources.filters.AuthenticationRequestFilter.filter(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest)
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5119)
```

and at the end it says

```
[#|2011-04-26T12:06:32.356+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}|#]
```

I am sure that the xml I send is correct according to database entries.(including authentication for the particular URL).

Is there anything like "container security". Whats may go wrong in this case.
Thanks in advance.